# listview in another listview is not expanding when items are added to it

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a listview containing a lot of different elements such as EditText, TextView and ListView.

I know it sounds a little weird to add a Listview in another Listview, but I have my reasons.
What I need to do, is making the inner Listview "scalable". It should expand and contract whenever items are added or removed from it.
I have tried giving the ListView the height: wrap_content, but it didn't do anything. When I add items to the list, they are simply hidden, as there are no room for them.

How can I make this inner ListView expand itself when items are added to it? 
(It needs to be a listview in a listview! So please, no other suggestions about other kinds of implementations:) )

Well here is the xml for the layout of the item containing the outer layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/trainingpass_headline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Trainingpass"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:height="35dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/trainingpass_showhide_imageview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:height="25dp"
        android:minWidth="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/trainingpass_headline"
        android:src="@mipmap/arrows_up_down"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/trainingpass_headline"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/trainingpass_headline"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/trainingpass_headline"
        android:id="@+id/trainingPassContainer"
        android:background="@color/blue_bg_neutral"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/trainingpass_exercise_searchfield"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:hint="Name of exercise"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:background="@color/blue_bg_inputField"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/trainingpass_exercise_searchfield"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:id="@+id/sets_container"
            android:background="@color/blue_bg_inputField"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_sets_for_exercise"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sets for exercise"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:paddingRight="30dp"
                android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                android:paddingTop="0dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/add_set_button"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/add_set_button" />

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/trainingpass_sets_listview"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txt_no_sets" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Add set"
                android:id="@+id/add_set_button"
                android:layout_below="@+id/trainingpass_sets_listview"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Add exercise"
                android:id="@+id/add_exercise_button"
                android:layout_below="@+id/add_set_button"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_no_sets"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="No sets yet"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:paddingRight="30dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt_sets_for_exercise"
                android:visibility="invisible" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sets_container"
            android:id="@+id/exercises_container"
            android:background="@color/blue_bg_inputField"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_exercises"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Exercises"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:paddingRight="30dp"
                android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                android:paddingTop="0dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txt_no_exercises_yet"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/txt_no_exercises_yet" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_no_exercises_yet"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="No exercises yet"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:paddingRight="30dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt_exercises"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/exercises_listview"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt_exercises"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_no_exercises_yet" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Delete"
            android:id="@+id/delete_trainingpass_button"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/exercises_container"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/exercises_container"
            android:layout_below="@+id/exercises_container"
            android:background="@color/btn_red"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Done"
            android:id="@+id/done_trainingpass_button"
            android:layout_below="@+id/exercises_container"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/exercises_container"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/exercises_container"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/delete_trainingpass_button"
            android:background="@color/btn_green"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The ListView I want to make expandable, is "trainingpass_sets_listview", in the above code.

Here is the xml layout for the items of "trainingpass_sets_listview":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:transitionGroup="true">

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="X"
        android:id="@+id/btn_delete_set"
        android:background="@color/btn_red"
        android:height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_minus_set" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/field_sets"
        android:minWidth="50dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:editable="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_plus_set"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn_plus_set" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:id="@+id/txt_setNo"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/field_sets" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+"
        android:id="@+id/btn_plus_set"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/field_sets"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt_setNo"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txt_setNo"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/blue_bg_inputField_darker" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-"
        android:id="@+id/btn_minus_set"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/field_sets"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/field_sets"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/blue_bg_inputField_darker"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/field_sets" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

If more information or code is needed, please just ask.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I know you stated "It needs to be a listview in a listview! So please, no other suggestions about other kinds of implementations", but since you want a listview in a listview why not try an expandable list view? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Comment: One does not simply put ListView in a ListView.. Could you maybe explain the reasons to this foolishness?

Comment: I agree… 'please, no other [implementation] suggestions' is a little silly. Sometimes the way you want to do it is not possible in Android. :) Unless write a custom view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It needs to be a listview in a listview!

You can't do it.  `ListViews` were not designed to be embedded within each other.  This further expands to: *Never embed scrollable widgets that scroll in the same direction*. It's one of the big no-no's in Android. While you can kinda sorta get something like that working...it'll have it's issues and never work 100%.

> So please, no other suggestions about other kinds of implementations:)

Then you are left with only a no answer to your question. However lets pretend it could work. Allow me to say additionally why you shouldn't go with your approach.

**Performance:**
Every `ListView` is backed by an adapter.  Each adapter has a method, `getView()` which is used for generating each item displayed to the screen in the `ListView`.  There is no guarantee how many times `getView()` will be invoked for each item's position when rendering to the screen. It's not abnormal to see it called 3-4 times per position.  If each position contained a `ListView` (as you are trying to do) which in turn had it's own adapter, then it'll additionally take multiple passes per item to render.  This all fast compounds the number of passes taken to render something to the screen and you are taking a big hit to performance.

**Re-Inventing the Wheel:**
As pointed out by @Fareya, Android has already provided a solution for creating such a UI look and it's called an `ExpandableListView`. It can easily do what you are trying to do.  You'll save on time and frustrations by utilizing it instead of attempting to roll your own solution.

Comment: "ListViews were not designed to be embedded within each other." Please follow these words of wisdom.

Comment: Okay I see your point. The reason I wanted to put a listview in a listview, was for learning purposes only. But I see now that this will never be a good approach. I'll go with the ExpandableListView. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom listview and override its `onMeasure` method like this.

```
public class UnscrollableListView extends ListView {

    public UnscrollableListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public UnscrollableListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public UnscrollableListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int maxHeightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec( 
                Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST); 
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, maxHeightSpec); 
    }

}
```

This will make the listview to wrap their content and scalable.

Using this listview as your inner listview will meet your needs.

Have a look on my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29817442/how-to-make-linearlayout-scrollable-with-two-listviews-scrollable-which-wrap-the/29819911#29819911).

Still I have to say that making `ListView` working in this way is not suggested.